# Facebook comment box moderation does not appear

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I added facebook comment box to my site but there is no moderation. I went to moderation tools page on facebook but none of the comments were there.

[image]
All the code that I used;

```
<!-- in head -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" />

<!-- in body -->
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-num-posts="10" data-width="100%"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: The code you've entered is irrelevant to your problem. All it does is load Facebook's Javascript SDK. You might want to look into Facebook's [Comment Box Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to gain a better understanding of what code needs to be added/edited.

Comment: what do you mean? Problem that I am having is with facebook's comment box moderation bar and I put the whole code here.

Comment: My apologies. You *did* post all relevant code, but it wasn't formatted correctly. I've provided the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest switching your tags around a bit to match the edit, as well as adding this into your head section:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
```

That property should enable you to moderate comments if you've provided your own ID. You can retrieve your ID from the very handy [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=35101664%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname).

If you read the documentation I provided in my earlier comment, you'll see all of the available options at your disposal to customize your comment box.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it, I thought I put it right but it wasn't apparently. I did put this code in but it didn't help. But now I just added again and it worked. I guess facebook's caching may have caused the problem. Appreciated.!

Comment: Anytime. In case you ever run into caching issues again, take a look into Facebook's [Debugging Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). This will clear Facebook's cache each time you check your website.